# SQL Join Table issue, duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am going crazy with this query here, I have tried so many different ways but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, or if it is at all possible. I have two tables 1 is for outcomes and other one for goals. There are many goals for one possible outcome. When I run the query I join the table to get all outcomes and all goals for a specific record. But I am getting duplicate results. Here is the result I am getting

Outcome 1 ** goal 1

Outcome 2 ** goal 1

Outcome 1 ** goal 2

Outcome 2 ** goal 2

this should be the expected result

Outcome 1 ** goal 1

Outcome 1 ** goal 2

Outcome 1 ** goal 3

Outcome 2 ** goal 4

Outcome 2 ** goal 5

Thank you so much for your help. Here is the query

```
SELECT rep_outcomes.description AS title, rep_goals.description, rep_goals.status 
FROM rep_goals LEFT JOIN rep_outcomes ON rep_goals.report_id = rep_outcomes.report_id
WHERE rep_goals.report_id = 2 ORDER BY rep_goals.id
```

Comment: could you please post the tables' definitions?

Comment: Join types shown as Venn diagrams: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0):

Throwing it out there but does Group by create the right data set?

So:

```
Group by XXX
Order by xxx
```

Comment: I had to restructure my tables add an outcome id in the goals table so that I can actually link the results

Comment: Oh so you got it by just combining the 2 tables together... well adding that one column?